# fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory despite the GTK library being installed on my windows system

Tags: c, windows, gcc, gtk, gtk4

I followed the msys2 installation shown on [the GTK website](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/) in order to code in C on my windows11 system.

I tried to compile the basic ["hello world" programm](https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world/) but it doesn't work, despite the library being correctly installed (as shown by the command pkg-config --cflags gtk4).

This is what it looks like on the windows cmd:

```
PS C:\ESGI\test> pkg-config --cflags gtk4

-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/gtk-4.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/pango-1.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/cairo -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/harfbuzz -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/freetype2 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/graphene-1.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/graphene-1.0/include -mfpmath=sse -msse -msse2 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/glib-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/fribidi -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/webp -DLIBDEFLATE_DLL -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/libpng16 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/pixman-1
```

```
PS C:\ESGI\test> gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk4) -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk4)

hello-world-gtk.c:1:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory

1 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>

| ^~~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.
```

Do you guys have any idea why it is the case and how to solve that problem ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is that syntax `$( ... )` in a command line supported under Windows at all? You could try to replace that command by the output you received when you called that program standalone.